# Deleting related models in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, delete-row

When I open update "page"  I have dynamically rows that are saved in the DB . But how I can manage to delete the rows in **actionUpdate**  to delete them in the DB.The deleted items are in array  with id deletedIDs

```
 public function actionUpdate($id) {

    $model = Component::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();

    $depModels = Dependency::find()->where(['component_id' => $id])->all();

    $tractorModels = ArrayHelper::map(Tractormodel::find()->all(), 'id', 'model');

    $components = Component::find()->all();


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $dependendComponents = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams['ids'];
        foreach ($dependendComponents as $dComp) {

            $dependencyModel = new Dependency();
            $dependencyModel->setAttributes([
                'count' => $dComp['quantity'],
                'component_id' => $model->id,
                'dependent_id' => $dComp['id']
            ]);
            $dependencyModel->save();
        }

        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
                    'model' => $model, 'tractorModels' => $tractorModels,
                    'components' => $components, 'depModels' => $depModels,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and here is my remove row jQUery in "_form"

```
wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {

        var wantedDiv = $(this).parent('div').children().first();
        var selectTag = $(wantedDiv).find('select');

        var clickedId = $(selectTag).find('[selected=""]').attr('value');

        var deletedIdsArray = $('#deletedIDs');

        console.log($('#deletedIDs'));

        if (clickedId) {
            $('#deletedIds').append('<input type="hidden" name="deletedIds[]" value="' + clickedId + '">');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look what you get in Yii::$app->request->post()
Try var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()).
If there is nothing there you need to change your input form. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html

And if you want to delete something from DB it would be better to use another Action: send data from you update form to actionDelet and change method logic according to your needs.

Comment: I receive information 
array(4) {
  ["_csrf"]=>
  string(56) "TFM5Tm9hSGM/CXcAIzIhMx0aSBYDEgMuBAFxIw0rDRAtEXEPDSULKw=="
  ["Component"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "proba"
    ["instock"]=>
    string(3) "333"
    ["tractormodel_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["ids"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(16) "Select component"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["deletedIds"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "15"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "13"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
}

Comment: but there should be a way to do it in acitonUpdate ,because there I delete these dynamically rows if I want ,  that I made when I create a "component".And like I said the deleted items I put them in array , but need a way how to delete them from the DB

Comment: then you need to add in your code something like this: 
 YourModel::deleteAll(['id' => Yii::$app->request->post()["deletedIds"]]);